# How to change default folder/file permissions for file sharing

Tags: permission, folders, sharing, file

I have 3 Macs on the network. Each has a Standard User account that is using the Mac.

User A has a folder with files that other user (B & C) can access.
When I first copied a bunch of files from a backup HDD to UserA Document Folder, all the files had permission 777.
So User B and User C can read, add to, and delete the files & folders

Now when UserA creates a new folderXYZ in the Document folder, the permission of folderXYZ is default to 744.
Hence only UserA can add files to folderXYZ. User B and C can read the files in folderXYZ, but cannot add or delete files in folderXYZ. Each time it tries to add or del files in folderXYZ, there is a prompt asking for admin user&password, which User B & C will not have as they are standard user.

If UserB create a folderPQR in User A's Document folder, the folder permission is set to 744 with respect to UserB. so UserA and UserC can only read the files in folderPQR, but cannot add or delete files in folderPQR. An admin password is needed too.

Every so often, I have to change the permissions of UserA Document folder from 744 to 777 and set it to "apply to enclosed item". Only after this can all UserA,B,C add and delete files in foldersXYZ,  folderPQR and any other folders UserA,B,C created within UserA Document folder.

[image]

How do I make it such that when any userA,B,C creates a new folder in the UserA Document folder, the permission is set to 777 automatically, rather than stays at the default 744 for the creator.

I have read about umask command which works only when terminal remains open and user-specific launchd configurations command, but would like to source for other advice before proceeding.

Thank you.

Comment: Why are you changing it so that everyone (public) has read/write/execute access?  This is not secure.  Just set "everyone" (like in the image above) to Read & Write in the parent folder.  This is not advisable and actually sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: It is a closed network with only 3 Mac. Even after I set "everyone" to Read & Write, the other users (A&B) cannot delete files or add files into the folder created by user C. Whoever creates the folder has access only, The others can only Read, can't even add files to the folder.